# Any workarounds to access websites that don't support IPv6?

Tags: windows-10, dns, ipv6, ipv4, twitch

Lately I have trouble accessing [*twitch.tv*](http://twitch.tv/) on any of my browsers and devices. Google Chrome gave me ***DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*** so I looked up on... Google and most articles told me to change my DNS. I went on changing DNS on every devices that I'm using to Google DNS. But it only worked on my phone which is Android. My computers, however, didn't work. After seatching around, I figured that Twitch doesn't support IPv6. So I went to Network and Sharing Center (Windows 10) to disable IPv6 protocol and Twitch is accessible again.

IPv6 has always been activated on my computer. Is there any problem if I disable IPv6 on my computer? If there is problems then what should I do to tackle this issue?

ps: I didn't know that my ISP support IPv6 until this problem occur :v.

Comment: As a comment, the majority of the internet is still on IPv4 so the potential impact (certainly for general browsing) is almost certainly little to none.

Comment: Twitch doesn't seem to be using IPv6...today. But it might have been on briefly as a test (which would have failed). You probably don't need to do anything on your end, and you probably should re-enable IPv6.

Comment: It's sort of funny that if you're on a network that only supports IPv6, if you search for help on Google and find this question, you won't be able to read it. (Because this site doesn't yet support IPv6 either.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Twitch doesn't support IPv6

Generally that doesn't *need* workarounds. Your computer won't just "use IPv6" for every site; it needs to know the website's IPv6 address first (the two protocols have fully separate addresses).

But websites which don't support IPv6 simply *don't publish any IPv6 address* in DNS – so there's nothing for your computer to try. When it only knows the IPv4 address, it only uses IPv4, no problems whatsoever.

(As an example, you're posting this on `superuser.com` which doesn't support IPv6 either.)

Much more likely is one of these:

- Your DNS server *rejects* all requests for IPv6 addresses (for `AAAA` records). That violates the protocol – if the domain exists but is IPv4-only, the correct response is "success" with no data (zero records of that type).
- The website supports IPv6 but your own IPv6 connection is broken, perhaps due to technical problems at your ISP's side. Check out a few "IPv6 test" websites.
- The website supports IPv6, but is simply unreachable at this moment due to technical problems. (Separate addressing means separate routing, it's always possible that v4 and v6 connections take completely different paths.)
- The website did support IPv6 at some point and published its IPv6 address; but then disabled IPv6 support and forgot to remove the address from DNS. That happens, but very unlikely for professionally managed sites like Twitch.
- The website doesn't support IPv6, but you use a "DNS64" DNS server which returns fake IPv6 addresses for NAT64 (a mechanism for v4/v6 translation)... and your ISP's NAT64 relay is broken. This is very unlikely, and doesn't match the error message you demonstrated.

---

In general, disabling IPv6 temporarily won't cause problems. Since many clients are IPv4-only to this day, all popular websites have to accept IPv4 as well – many of them are dualstack IPv4/v6, but you won't find a website that *requires* IPv6 to be used.

But it is a fairly crude workaround; I wouldn't keep it disabled for too long – just out of principle. I would suggest trying to find out the actual source of the problem, whether it's in your router or your ISP.

Comment: My ISP is testing their IPv6 and they must have messed up something. For now, I just gonna disable IPv6 on my computers because that the only way I can access Twitch.

Comment: Perhaps they thought NAT64 was a good idea, or something. Do share the output of `nslookup -q=AAAA twitch.tv` (from your ISP's standard DNS servers) if you can.

Comment: Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1

*** No IPv6 address (AAAA) records available for twitch.tv

Comment: My ISP said thay have IPv6 but the online tests said no.

Comment: So your DNS response is correct (for the main Twitch site at least). The lookup _itself_ was done over IPv6 though – perhaps Chrome doesn't understand how to deal with DNS servers having link-local addresses (`fe80:*`)... And as for your ISP, they only provide IP until your router; the router has to provide it for the local network.